# How should I set up and deploy my django project that spans over multiple subdomains and multiple databases?

Tags: django, apache, hosting, wsgi, multiple-databases

Let's say I'm building a Django driven site that hosts web shops, let's call it webshop.com. I want it to work like this:

A shop named Foo would like a webshop. They register at webshop.com and the subdomain foo.webshop.com is created, as well as the database foo_DB. The owners of Foo enter their products using an admin interface at foo.webshop.com/admin. Customers can then buy the products from foo.webshop.com.

The the shop Bar has the webshop bar.webshop.com - completely unrelated to the other webshops hosted at webshop.com. And so on. webshop.com should be able to host 100's of stores.

The question is: how should I go about doing this with Django?

At first I was thinking that I should have one settings.py file, one virtual server and one database for each webshop. However I fear that it can be generated too much overhead from running all those instances.

Any pointers or thoughts is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use`django-sudomains` https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains/

It is a middleware which creates a subdomain property for each request.

Since the functionality for each site is the same you could then just query for products based on sudomain requested.  You could also assign users a subdomain.

All views would be the same except they would take into account this subdomain.  This approach could work easy with 1 shared database where each model has a field that points to the subdomain or a shared database with subdomains being the database naem. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset

Answer (score 1):

I've built half a dozen applications that work like this (though none in python, but it's really irrelevant in this case).

Serve everything from the same virtual host.  Get the server name with [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) Once you have the string you want to match, do a lookup in a master database for the database details which match your customer database (ie the hostname, username, password, etc.).  Make sure you sanitize that value before querying on it.

I do think your best bet is separating your customers databases.  Not only does this ensure that one database problem doesn't bring down all your customer sites, it also allows you to put them on different servers.

Comment: Thanks! But what's the best practice for doing this in Django?

Comment: One settings.py file for all sites.  One virtual host for all sites.  One database for each webshop.